# How do I disable relative URL references to Nuget Packages in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a code library that needs a Nuget Package. I also have a application that needs to reference the same Nuget package.

If I open either project alone and add the Nuget Package to the Project in Visual Studio using Nuget Pacakge manager its added to [PackageName]\Packages. Which is what I would expect.

However if I open both projects in visual Studio at the same time VS immediately assumes I want a "solution" this is fine it's basically an organizational thing for VS but now the way packages are added changes the first package is still added to [ProjectName]\Packages but when I reference it from the second project I get a reference path of ..[FirstProjectName]\Packages.

If I perchance then add a Nuget package to the second project and then minutes or months later add the same Nuget package to the first project I've now got the same reference mess in reverse. Fast forward a couple months and the project structure inter-dependency is a cobweb of referential urls. With specific file structure dependencies. Move a project, delete it or just don't get a local copy because you aren't working with it and the whole thing goes BOOM!

How do I disable this functionality and make the adding of packages function the same whether I open 1 project or open 2. In both cases I would expect the package to install in [ProjectName]\Packages not install the first time and reference the second.

Note: adding a "solution wide" common nuget package directory is exactly what I don't want. Each project needs to be independent. Capable of compiling and running without any dependency on a structure beyond the project directory and the functional dependencies, explicitly referenced by project, for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting a repository path to a drive different than my projects, or setting a repository path to a UNC path.

I did this by editing my Nuget.Config file (usually found here %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config) and adding a Repository Path setting.

*Note that I use the D drive for code-related files.*

```
<config>
  <add key="repositorypath" value="\\localhost\d$\NuGet\packages" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a project specific packages directory is not supported with NuGet when using the Visual Studio tooling.

NuGet's packages directory is defined by the current solution the project is being opened within Visual Studio.

The packages directory is either implicitly the $(SolutionDir)\packages directory or it is a custom path defined by the NuGet.Config file that it finds based on the current solution's directory. The NuGet.Config file is found by looking in several directories but it is still driven by the location of the current solution.

With NuGet 3 and the introduction of the project.json file you can now have references without having them added to the project file so you do not have the problem with relative paths to assemblies. However not all projects have support for the new project.json. Also you are using Visual Studio 2013 which does not support NuGet 3.

So your only workarounds are either:

1. Use a common packages directory for all solutions.
2. Ensure all solutions are in a common directory relative to the project files.
3. Write some utility which automatically warns about incorrect reference paths, or automatically fixes them.
4. Modify NuGet so it supports what you are trying to do.

Comment: To say Nuget doesnt support it is bit of a stretch the Nuget Restore and Add command line Commands work fine and restore to whichever directory is dictated. and the VS Plugin works fine with a single target. The issue isn't with Nuget it would at least be with the Visual Studio plugin.

Comment: @David - Fair point about the command line NuGet.exe. The problem with using the command line is that when using `NuGet.exe install package` is it does not modify the project file. It only downloads files to the packages directory. Only NuGet.exe update will modify the project file. NuGet restore will similarly only download NuGet packages to the packages directory without modifying the project file. I was assuming your question was about Visual Studio integration.